# How to set request headers in titanium

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

Is there any way that i can set request headers in titanium?.

eg: API = abcdefgb56432142345234534;

my xhr:

```
var url = "http://www.appcelerator.com";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    // function called when the response data is available
    onload: function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout: 5000 // in milliseconds
});
// Prepare the connection.
client.open("GET", url);
// Send the request.
client.send();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes try the below,

Always set after opening the request

```
var url = "http://www.appcelerator.com";
var client = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
    // function called when the response data is available
    onload: function(e) {
        Ti.API.info("Received text: " + this.responseText);
        alert('success');
    },
    // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
    onerror: function(e) {
        Ti.API.debug(e.error);
        alert('error');
    },
    timeout: 5000 // in milliseconds
});
// Prepare the connection.
client.open("GET", url);

client.setRequestHeader('API','abcdefgb56432142345234534'); //allways set after open
// Send the request.
client.send();
```

Comment: @user3475082 Oppz my bad..check the code i have updated

Comment: Wow works like charm..you saved my day...thanks @jlocker :)

Comment: Great...if my answer helped you please accept it as the answer.